# Angular expression not resolved

Tags: angularjs

I am testing the following angular [example](https://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/17):

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){
        $scope.names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe'];

        $scope.addName = function() {
          $scope.names.push($scope.enteredName);
          $scope.enteredName = '';
        };

        $scope.removeName = function(name) {
          var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
          $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}
        <a href="" ng-click="removeName(name)">remove</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="addName()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="enteredName">
      <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the output:

- remove
- remove
- remove

The remove link works, and I'm also able to add new items, but the `{{name}}` is empty. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your exact code into a JSFiddle, and I can see the names clearly. https://jsfiddle.net/fp3r2gf4/

```
* Larry remove
* Curly remove
* Moe remove
```

So, perhaps it is your browser. I viewed it in Chrome. Perhaps you can inspect the actual HTML with your browser's developer tools and see if the text is there, but hidden with CSS.